# Sybase IMAGE_LOCATOR type

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I'm having trouble with the Sybase type IMAGE_LOCATOR, namely not being able to find out anything about it.

```
Error while query: INSERT INTO PPGT_TPC (.,.,.,.,.,.,.) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
JZ0BE: BatchUpdateException: Error occurred while executing batch statement: Explicit conversion from datatype 'IMAGE_LOCATOR' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed.
```

My biggest problem is that I can't find any documentation about the IMAGE_LOCATOR type so that can I at least start my analysis somewhere.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Image Locator may be a user defined data type.  It is not an ASE data type.  http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X45882.htm

Comment: @MichaelGardner, Thanks for the answer, but it's nowhere in my code. Could it be coming from JDBC/Sybase Open Client?

Comment: do `sp_help "IMAGE_LOCATOR"`

Comment: text_locator and image_Locator were introduced in ASE v.15.7 as system datatypes. They are sometimes colelctively referred to as 'LOB locators'. See here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/blocks109.htm and here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20116.1570/html/aseodbc/CIHGAFCE.htm
These links are just starters... search the ASE docs above for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this error message while *not* using IMAGE_LOCATOR in your code, then you must be hitting a bug in Sybase.

In some SPs of ASE 15.7, when running dynamic prepared statements from a user that has auditing turned on, this error is incorrectly thrown.

You may want to turn auditing off to confirm, and contact your SAP support.

Now since the question was about IMAGE_LOCATOR -

IMAGE_LOCATOR is an ASE datatype that represents a pointer to an IMAGE datatype. It is a particular type of the LOB locators which were introduced in ASE 15.7.
(http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20155.1570/html/OS_SDK_nf/CIHJIIHB.htm)

By default you shouldn't have to manipulate LOB locators; but if you want to you can set `send_locator` to "on" in your session. (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug223.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off auditing.. we had the same problem and it was resolved by turning off auditing